# Sorting dynamic array c

Tags: c, sorting

```
typedef struct spieler* pSpieler;

struct spieler
{
   char vorname[LENGTH];
   char nachname[LENGTH];
   int rueckennummer;
   int erzielteTore;
   pSpieler pNext;
};
```

The function sortiereTore should sort the elements of the list that the one with the least value for erzielteTore is the first and the one with the highest value should be the last one.

```
void sortiereTore()
{
   pSpieler pPrev = pErsterSpieler;
   pSpieler pAkt = pErsterSpieler;
   pSpieler pAfter = pAkt->pNext;
   int flag = 1;
   while(flag != 0)
   {
       flag = 0;

       while (pAfter != NULL)
       {
           if ((pAfter->erzielteTore) < (pAkt->erzielteTore))
           {
               if (pAkt == pErsterSpieler)
               {
                   pErsterSpieler = pAfter;
               }
               pAkt->pNext = pAfter->pNext;
               pAfter->pNext = pAkt;
               pPrev->pNext = pAfter;
               flag = 1;
               pPrev = pAfter;
               pAfter = pAkt->pNext;
           }
           else
           {
               pPrev = pAkt;
               pAkt = pAfter;
               pAfter = pAfter->pNext;
           }
       }

       pPrev = pErsterSpieler;
       pAkt = pErsterSpieler;
       pAfter = pAkt->pNext;

   }
}
```

I don't have a clue how to solve the problem and hope anyone could help me. 
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: what you have is a linked list not a dynamic array

Comment: well yeah, i created a linked list with a dynamic array

Comment: Could you make a [mcve] for this?

Comment: i've changed it - hope it's better now

Comment: There's a billion and a half ways to sort an array. What method are you trying to do? I can't easily read the code since the variable names are throwing me off.

Comment: Is pPrev correct if the very first element needs to move?

Comment: Ich empfehle, die Bezeichner und sonstigen deutschen Ausdrücke zu übersetzen. Das wird einerseits den Lesern helfen eine Antwort zu finden. Andererseits bietet es einen neuen Blickwinkel auf den eigenen Code, wie mit Momo zu sprechen. I recommend translating identifiers and other German expressions. On the one hand that will help readers finding an answer, on the other hand it will provide a fresh perspective of your code, like rubber-ducking.

Comment: Would you be open to using `qsort` from the standard c library?

Answer (score 0):

Let's interpret this question as "How do I debug my program?" rather than "What is wrong with my program?" because answering the second will get you exactly nowhere as a programmer. You must learn to fix bugs yourself.

Debugging your own program is at heart always the same. Here's the crux:

> There is *a difference between what you think your code does and what it actually does*. This is preventing you from seeing where to change the code to make it correct.

Consequently, proceed in two steps:

1. Eliminate the difference between your thinking and what's actually happening. Then your mental model will coincide with what the program is actually doing rather than your erroneous idea of what you *think* it's doing.
2. Use your new, correct knowledge of what your program's doing to design and implement a fix for the actual behavior. If your program is close to correct, this is a very small step. But sometimes - if your initial thinking was far from correct - you may need to throw away your first try and begin again.

Step 1 - especially for little learning programs like this one - often starts with creating the smallest example you can that has the bug. (Hence, the SO practice of proving a MCVE.) Then execute the program statement by statement, visualizing each step, until you produce the bad result.
"Statement by statement" can mean single-stepping with a debugger, inserting `print`s so the program itself generates a trace, or using your own head as the processor, with a paper and pencil for memory.

> No matter what you do, your effort is to ***learn*** where the program's actual execution diverges from your idea of its execution.

In other words, your goal is to find *some particular statement* where you *thought* the program was setting some variable to some value (or not), and it is actually setting a different value, not setting at all (or in fact setting it when you thought it wasn't).

At this point, the understanding must come. "The light must go on." It will feel great to have mastered your own error. Congratulations!

Then proceed with step 2.

The more you do this, the better you'll become at it. But you *must* do it yourself. You can't learn debugging by asking people to debug for you.

Comment: @MarkSegal Well, he never got around to asking a question. At least I'm not seeing a question mark anywhere. He said "I don't have a clue."  I tried to give him a clue.